# What is the right way of static registration of custom Broadcast receiver in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

Instead of dynamic registration, I want to statically register my receiver. 
**For dynamic registration, it works well, I was using this :**

```
..
static private IntentFilter GPSActionFilter;
..
GPSActionFilter = new IntentFilter("GGPS Service");
context.registerReceiver(GPSActionReceiver, GPSActionFilter);
..
static private BroadcastReceiver GPSActionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  ..}
```

**For static registration, debugger never hits the onReceive function, I am using this:**

In AndoridManifest :

```
<receiver android:name="LocationListener$GPSActionReceiver" >   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="LocationListener.ACTION_GPS_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In code :

```
public class LocationListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static IntentFilter GPSActionFilter;
    public static final String ACTION_GPS_SERVICE = "com.example.LocationListener.GPSActionFilter";
    public static BroadcastReceiver GPSActionReceiver;
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {..}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring an intent-filter action in the manifest, the android:name must be a string literal and can not access Strings from classes. Also, I recommend you prepend your fully qualified package name to the intent action ie:

```
public static final String GPS_SERVICE = "com.example.LocationListener.ACTION_GPS_SERVICE"
```

Then change

```
<action android:name="LocationListener.GPS_SERVICE" />
```

To

```
<action android:name="com.example.LocationListener.ACTION_GPS_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have incorporated it. From my understanding, the broadcaster service is broadcasting and the receiver is being registered to listen to one particular intent i.e. ACTION_GPS_SERVICE. Is that so? Or does the listener listen to all the broadcasts? If not, the ACTION_GPS_SERVICE will need to be defined by the broadcaster service, right?

Comment: The broadcast receiver will listen only for an intent with the action com.example.LocationListener.ACTION_GPS_SERVICE so the broadcaster will need to send an intent with this action. The broadcaster service can send a broadcast like this: context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(LocationListener.GPS_SERVICE));

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot have a `private` `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, as Android needs to be able to create an instance of it. Please make this public.

Second, the syntax for the name of static inner classes is `LocationListener$GPSActionReceiver`, not `LocationListener.GPSActionReceiver`.

Comment: The private BroadcastReceiver is not there for the static registration. Infact, When I have the tags in the AndroidManifest, I do not have a BroadcastReceiver in the code. If I am registering the GPSActionReceiver in the AndroidManifest, why would I need to have newBroadcastreceiver()? I only have an onReceive method inside the LocationListener class. Thanks for the syntax suggestion. I have corrected that.

Comment: @user1736947: The `android:name` attribute on `<receiver>` needs to point to a public Java class. Yours, apparently, does not.