# Android how to keep alive broadcast receiver when app is closed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have register a broadcast receiver to filter phone call actions but when app is closed my broadcast receiver never start  when phone starting ringing from incoming calls.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALL" />
 <receiver
        android:name=".handlers.IncomingCallHandler"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000000000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701940/what-is-the-right-way-of-static-registration-of-custom-broadcast-receiver-in-and 

This may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your receiver to run even when Application is closed, start it from a service [Run Receiver Forever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824692/3159267)